# jquery aloha-editor, Aloha.triger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've question about Aloha.trigger in page
http://aloha-editor.org/guides/events.html#aloha-editable-created-event
How to use practically

```
Aloha.trigger( 'aloha-smart-content-changed', {
    'editable'          : , // object of the editable
    'keyIdentifier'     : , // char | null
    'keyCode'           : , // char | null
    'char'              : , // char | null
    'triggerType'       : , // keypress, idle, blur, paste, block-change
    'snapshotContent'   : , // snapshot content of the editable as HTML String
} );
```

or

```
Aloha.trigger( 'aloha-editable-created', [
    // jQuery object reference of an editable
] );
```

practically? I cannot find eny example. Only Aloha.bind can be found

```
Aloha.bind( 'aloha-editable-created', function( jEvent, editable ) {
    console.log( 'editable "' + editable.getId() + '" created' );
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use Some thing like this

```
Aloha.bind( 'aloha-smart-content-changed', function( jEvent, aEvent){
      // Get updated content
  console.log( this, jEvent, aEvent.getSnapshotContent() );
      // Get the object that is updated - jQ object 
  console.log($(aEvent.editable.obj).eq(0);
});
```